# Python Script Error When Executed In Terminal (Trutle Module)

Tags: python, linux

So, I wrote a simple game, with the trutle module in Python. When I execute it, by doubleclicking it, it works just fine. But if I execute it in the Terminal, using `sudo python3 SpaceWars.py` it won't work.

Here's the error Message:

[image: Error Message]

I'm Sorry for the Picture. I was too lazy to retype the code.

Hardware / Software:

Machine: Raspberry PI 3 Model B

OS: Retropie (Based on Raspbian)

Python Version: Python 3.4.2 default [GCC 4.9.1 on linux]

Here's the Code: https://pastebin.com/ZERS2V9g

Can someone help me?

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: You run it with `python3`, but your error message talks about `python2.7`

Comment: If I run it with Python 2.7, I get the same error message.

Comment: Why do you execute it as the superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable` says it: it is unknown where to display the graphics. If the `$DISPLAY` variable was set, it got lost due to the `sudo`. You can try to preserve it by means of the `-E` (*preserve environment*) option:

```
sudo -E python3 SpaceWars.py
```

But the question remains whether you really have to execute it as the superuser.